# python でテキストの行数を取得したい

Tags: python

pythonでテキストデータの行数を取得したいです
1行読み込む毎にint型変数をインクリメントする以外に良い方法はありますか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

他人の投稿で申し訳ありませんが、全く同じような質問が出ていたのでこちらに。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python

本家で議論された内容で、以下の内容が最も評価されているようです。

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019572

以下に引用して載せておきます

```
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('myfile.txt'))
```

Comment: `num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('myfile.txt'))`
これでどうでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。助かりました。

Answer (score 4):

行数を数えるだけで良ければ

```
len(open('hoge.txt').readlines())
```

では、どうでしょうか。